# Cannot do git-svn fetch behind proxy

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to mirror a svn repo using git-svn.

I'm doing

```
git svn clone http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind
```

And I'm getting

```
Initialized empty Git repository in f:/gstest/WorldWind/.git/
RA layer request failed: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/trunk/WorldWind': PROPFIND of '/svn/trunk/WorldWind': could not connect to server (http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148
```

If I do the same on another computer that isn't within the proxy it's ok.

I'm on a win7, and I've set  `$HTTP_PROXY`, `http.proxy` (the global one in git) and `$HOME/AppData/Roaming/Subversion/servers` to the correct proxy.

Doing `svn checkout [repo adress]` in a shell works.
Doing `wget [repo adress]` in a shell works.
But not `git svn clone [repo adress]`

Any ideas? Most of the questions I've found on this points me to the `Subversion/servers` file, but now I've edited that one and the problem is still there... :/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

And the solution is finding the correct Subversion configuration directory. At least in my case the native `svn.exe` uses the file `C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers`, but `git-svn` uses `~/.subversion/servers`. And I mean this path `~/.subversion/servers` in the Git Bash shell, where `~` is expanded to the right location. Edit `~/.subversion/servers` the same way as the other one used by `svn.exe` and then `git svn clone` should work.

In short, the key is finding the right configuration file to edit, as you may have multiple of them in Windows.

Comment: This solved my problem, and I feel pretty stupid for not recognizing it at first... I searched for all files called 'servers' on local hard drives and only found one. So that was the one I edited. (C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers) However, at my workplace the home catalogue is mapped to a network drive too.  And there was a M:\.subversion\servers file that I didn't find the first time.... :( when I edited that one git svn worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

To get svn to work behind a proxy on linux, update the file `~/.subversion/servers` with the proxy details.

```
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
http-proxy-host = YOURPROXY.com
http-proxy-port = YOURPORT
# http-proxy-username = defaultusername
# http-proxy-password = defaultpassword
# http-compression = no
# http-auth-types = basic;digest;negotiate
# No http-timeout, so just use the builtin default.
# No neon-debug-mask, so neon debugging is disabled.
# ssl-authority-files = /path/to/CAcert.pem;/path/to/CAcert2.pem
```

I guess there's a similar configuration on windows...

Comment: Yep i think it should be equivalent to C:\Users\[me]\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\servers, at least the file looks the same. And i've edited it, but it doesn't work anyway :/

Comment: That's a shame. Sorry I couldn't help you solve your problem. What does google tell you?

Comment: Thanks for the effort! Google tells me the same pretty much, change in .subversion/servers... Is there any way to see what proxy settings are actually used with git-svn? Perhaps some kind of verbose setting to either 'git svn clone' or 'git svn fetch'?

Comment: Key things to remember on Windows: 1) Update the section [global] not [group1] or [othergroup] etc... 2) Update both C:\Users\USERACCOUNTNAME\.subversion and C:\Users\local_admin\AppData\Roaming\Subversion (which will work on Windows 7 at least).

Comment: If the above doesn't work, make sure you're in the [global] section and not the [groups] section :-)

Comment: It works OK under Windows 7 with the latest git-for-windows(git version 2.21.0.windows.1). Tod Thomson's method is correct. I think someone can add to Fredrik Pihl's answers.

Comment: To me seems like C:\Users\USERACCOUNTNAME\.subversion is the correct location to edit. Works like a charm, thanks for tip!

Answer (score 5):

Usually, the environment variables alone:

- `HTTP_PROXY`
- `HTTPS_PROXY`
- `NO_PROXY`

are enough for git or git-svn to work properly.

But what gets me is the exact url to use.
For instance:

- `HTTP_PROXY=wwww.myproxy.company:8080` won't work, but
- `HTTP_PROXY=http://wwww.myproxy.company:8080` will work.

Use the same for `HTTPS_PROXY`, meaning the same *http* address (I tried first putting an https url for the `HTTPS_PROXY`, but that is not how it works)

Of course, if you need to authenticate, you can (at least for testing purposes) add your login/passname in it:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://myLogin:myPassword@wwww.myproxy.company:8080
```

And it helps setting the `NO_PROXY` one too: `localhost,*.company`.

---

So the main point behind this answer is "double check the exact url you are using" (and test it with a simple `curl http://www.google.com`, or with `wget`, either from the msysgit package or from [`Gnu On Windows`](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki))

Comment: Interesting, I'll try this on monday! I think I've entered HTTP_PROXY without 'http://'

Comment: No luck... After including 'http://' in the proxy settings the problem remains. I can do wget google.com, however when I do it still shows my proxy without 'http://'. I wonder if it trunkates away the 'http://' or if it's still without it... :/ If I do wget on the adress of the svn repo I can connect to it too.

Comment: @bjarven You mention it still shows my proxy without 'http://'. Can you detail a bit what shows that proxy without http, and how it is displayed? If I understand correctly, now the wget works, but the svn operations involving net connections still don't work, is that correct?

Comment: when I do wget, I get a line in the result like; 'looking up myproxy.com... [ip number]. (without http://) wget [repo adress] works, doing 'svn checkout [repo adress]' works, but not 'git svn clone [repo adress]'

Comment: @bjarven ok. The output is normal then (for `wget`).

Comment: @bjarven Now `git svn`should use the perl module [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/module/LWP::UserAgent#Proxy_attributes) for proxy management, and it mentions: "On systems with case insensitive environment variables there exists a name clash between the CGI environment variables and the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable normally picked up by `env_proxy()`. Because of this `HTTP_PROXY` is not honored for CGI scripts. The `CGI_HTTP_PROXY` environment variable can be used instead." Can you try playing with the case, or setting `CGI_HTTP_PROXY` just in case it would work?

Comment: i have tried all cases and tried setting CGI_HTTP_PROXY too, no luck... i'm not very fluent in perl but i tried a small script that tried to access the svn-repo, and it worked when i had HTTP_PROXY with http://, but not without. i got the proxy settings with env_proxy(). so with these env_proxy() settings i'm at least able to access the server in a perl script, but git-svn i still not working... :/

Comment: @bjarven that means git-svn doesn't take into account those environment variables. What version of git-svn are we talking about? Maybe it is possible to modify that perl `env_proxy()` setting globally, in order for the perl script from git-svn to pick it up?

Comment: @bjarven Maybe it is possible to modify that perl env_proxy() setting globally, in order for the perl script from git-svn to pick it up?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in C:\Users\YOU\.subversion\servers for the settings. You're looking for something inside this file like...

```
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
http-proxy-host = 127.0.0.1
http-proxy-port = 3128
```

... These settings are for CNTLM. Uncomment the lines I have uncommented above & put your own details in. There are fields for passwords etc. Fixed it for me getting stuff from Sourceforge. Yeah, Sourceforge is still there.

Also, CNTLM is great for getting through NTLM, forefront etc. Run Fiddler2 & set the rules to "Automatically Authenticate" to true to pick up any auth that CNTLM misses. Chrome updates are one thing that Fiddler fixes for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was just to change **url** in **config**.
Because I wasn't able to access the existing one.
To check I simply accessed the repo url using my browser.
In case of using forbidden url I got **'403 Forbidden'**.