# How to temporarily disable git http proxy

Tags: git, http-proxy

I am using git behind a corporate firewall, and I am successfully cloning external projects by using the http.proxy --global config.

My problem arises when I want to clone through http on the intranet. I suspect that the proxy config interferes with the intranet request.

I know I could reset the config before using the intranet, but that is not very user friendly.

I also saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16612442/28275), but it seems to apply only to an existing repository.

Is there a way to deactivate the proxy usage only for one command invocation? In this case, the initial clone?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I always set:

```
no_proxy=.mycompany
```

(`export` if I am on Unix, or a simple `set` on Windows)

It is enough to bypass the proxy for all intranet url ending with "`.mycompany`".

See for an example:

- "[Can't update/install using composer behind a corporate firewall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18458500/6309)"
- "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309)"
- "[Cannot do `git-svn fetch` behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169210/6309)"

I use it in my own project: [`.proxy.example`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/.proxy.example):

```
export http_proxy=http://username:userpassword@server.company:port
export https_proxy=http://username:userpassword@server.company:port
export no_proxy=.company localhost
```

Comment: I wish I could up vote it multiple times! I spent days trying to figure this damn thing out! Thank you man!

Answer (score 26):

What I like to do is set two Git aliases:

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[alias]
        noproxy = config --global --remove-section http
        proxy = config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:9666
```

Note that I didn't use `config --global --unset http.proxy` to reset the proxy because that leaves behind the `[http]` section heading, so after repeatedly enabling and disabling the proxy your `.gitconfig` will be polluted with a bunch of empty `[http]` section headings. No big deal, but it's just annoying.

---

In some cases, such as behind corporate firewalls, you need to configure `~/.ssh/config` instead. The setup becomes slightly more complicated:

**~/.gitconfig**

```
[alias]
        noproxy = !sh -c 'cp ~/.ssh/config.noproxy ~/.ssh/config'
        proxy = !sh -c 'cp ~/.ssh/config.proxy ~/.ssh/config'
```

**~/.ssh/config.noproxy**

```
Host github.com-username
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

**~/.ssh/config.proxy**

```
Host *
  ProxyCommand connect -H 127.0.0.1:9666 %h %p

Host github.com-username
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

You can even combine the two methods by changing the aliases to this:

```
[alias]
        noproxy = !sh -c 'git config --global --remove-section http 2> /dev/null && cp ~/.ssh/config.noproxy ~/.ssh/config'
        proxy = !sh -c 'git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:9666 && cp ~/.ssh/config.proxy ~/.ssh/config'
```

---

Now I can simply type `git noproxy` to disable the proxy and `git proxy` to enable it. You can even switch among multiple proxies by creating more aliases.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was able to disable git clone requests going through the proxy in my corporate setting by executing

`git config --global --add remote.origin.proxy ""`

As per the git documentation, this disables all requests to that remote repo named origin.