# Gitblit Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, gitblit

Trying to setup Gitblit (http://gitblit.com/setup_go.html) to make it easier for those on my team to access what we've got going on.

Anyway, I followed the instructions on this site: (http://gitblit.com/setup_go.html)

And now have a project in `https://localhost:8443/repositories/`

For access permissions I have two sets project_users and admin

Access restrictions are set to:  authenticated clone & push
Auuthorization control: grant RW+ permission to all authenticated users
I also users to fork

When I go to the project page I'm told there's nothing there and to add some comments and push to `https://admin@localhost:8443/r/myProject.git`

So I run : `git clone https://admin@localhost:8443/r/myProject.git` and am given the error:

```
Cloning into 'myProject'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://admin@localhost:8443/r/myProject.git/': Received HTTP code 504 from proxy after CONNECT
```

Is there something else configuration wise that I'm missing?

Comment: The proxy connect message is unusual. Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523903/how-to-temporarily-disable-git-http-proxy) will have useful information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment, I found some more information:

Solution was as follows:

```
1. set system_variable NO_PROXY = localhost
```

`2. run git config http.sslVerify=false` If developing on the machine that holds the repo