# Https github.com website opens but I cannot clone using CommandLine

Tags: git, github, git-clone, github-for-windows

I have this issue (which is already discussed in many threads here) but still can't find a way to the solution in my case, `https://www.github.com` opens normally, but when I try to `clone` a project from `Github` using `https`, I get this error :

[image]

I work in a company where I'm connected via `proxy` (which is detected automatically), I was told I should add that to the `.gitconfig` file, I tried that in both ways (`git config --global ...`) or manually by writing to the file so, I added the proxy for https in the .gitconfig file :

```
[https] proxy = https://172.16.0.254:8080
```

But I still have the same problem, what should I do to make this work, I appreciate the help.

PS : Pinging the website gives me :

```
Request timed out. Request timed out. Request timed out. Request timed out. Ping statistics for 192.30.252.128: Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

Comment: Are you sure your proxy is accessed through https? It is usually accessed through http only: `http://172.16.0.254:8080`

Comment: @VonC : Infrastructure people here are terrible, I explained to them your comment, but they said that this proxy accept both, (and I'm personally not into networking so I can't really ... is there something else I can do ?

Comment: If it accepts both, did you try `git config https.proxy = http://172.16.0.254:8080`?

Comment: I have done this : git config --global https.proxy https://172.16.0.254:8080 and it didn't work, but I'll try yours too, and I'll tell

Comment: Using an `http://172.16.0.254:8080` avoid having to use (internal company) certificates. That is why a proxy is always accessed through http. Even for defining https.proxy.

Comment: @VonC : I tried it, still get the same error.

Comment: Then forget about the git config, and try (still with `http://`) with environment variables: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524910/6309

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65159/discussion-between-aymendaoudi-and-vonc).