# Set up git-svn proxy with jenkins

Tags: jenkins, git-svn

Ok, this is kinda related to a previous question i asked; [Cannot do git-svn fetch behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15095561/cannot-do-git-svn-fetch-behind-proxy)

But this time I need an automated jenkins script that does `git svn fetch` to a repository that's outide our proxy.

As I found out in the other question, git-svn uses the proxy settings that's specified in the file `servers`. And `servers` is located at ~/.subversion.

Jenkins is set up on a machine running Windows server 2008, and I've searched for every `servers` file on the machine and modified them all, but I still isn't able to do `git svn fetch` without failing at the proxy.

I've tried to put a `.subversion` folder in the workspace, since ~ evaluates to the current workspace (I think) in jenkins, but that didn't work either.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables are ignored by both Git and Subversion.

You can check inside a jenkins job where the ~ path is with a small powershell script:

```
get-item  ~
```

I guess it will be:

> C:\Users\MYUSER.subversion\servers

Comment: This is interesting! I also think those environment variables won't matter. When I do `get-item ~` it says the variable Isn't set. The error message recommends setting it with `(get-psprovider 
'FileSystem').Home = 'path'`, and I've tried that but it still won't work. Do you know if setting it only will affect the powershell environment or also git and svn?

Comment: It seems to be local for the powershell instance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try and set, either as environment variable on the machine, or as environment variable on the job itself (with the [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin) the variables:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
HTTPS_PROXY=http://<username>:<password>@<proxy>:<port>
NO_PROXY=.<company>
```

Having the password set directly isn't secure, but this is only for testing, for you to check if the `git svn clone` can proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried and it didn't work unfortunately. But that plugin was nice, it'll probably come in handy sometime. :)

Comment: @bjarven strange, it should have worked. I like the plugin as it avoids setting env variables for one user before discovering Jenkins is running as another user.

Comment: I've tried setting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY directly as system variables before, and that didn't work either. I guess git svn looks for the proxy setting in some strange place... :/

Comment: @bjarven I just had an issue with EnvInject where the environment variable wasn't recognized when it was written in all uppercase. Can you try with: `Http_proxy=http://...` (first letter in uppercase, the rest in lowercase)?

Comment: Ok, tried that and still no result I'm afraid... :(