# How can I get remote package for Go?

Tags: git, go

I have problem with importing gin package into my Go project.

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080
}
```

I'm using `go get` command to install gin package, but it doesn't work.

```
C:\Users\YShipovalov\Desktop\Golang\helloworld>go get -v github.com/gin-gonic/gi
n
Fetching https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8?go-get=1: di
al tcp 45.33.37.13:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the targe
t machine actively refused it.
package gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/
go-playground/validator.v8" (https fetch: Get https://gopkg.in/go-playground/val
idator.v8?go-get=1: dial tcp 45.33.37.13:443: connectex: No connection could be
made because the target machine actively refused it.)
Fetching https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1
https fetch failed: Get https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp 45.33.37.13:
443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively
refused it.
package gopkg.in/yaml.v2: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/yaml.v2" (https fet
ch: Get https://gopkg.in/yaml.v2?go-get=1: dial tcp 45.33.37.13:443: connectex:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)
```

I have set proxy settings in git,so can this be a problem?

Comment: Take a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
  go get gopkg.in/gin-gonic/gin.v1
```

That will import a fixed version of that framework.

See for instance "[Build RESTful API service in golang using gin-gonic framework](https://medium.com/@thedevsaddam/build-restful-api-service-in-golang-using-gin-gonic-framework-85b1a6e176f3)"

But if you have proxy issue, that import should fail too.
As seen in "[Building Go Web Applications and Microservices Using Gin](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/building-go-web-applications-and-microservices-using-gin)", go `get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin` should work too.

Try removing proxy directive in your `.gitconfig`.

Try instead setting `HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY` (make sure to use http url in both cases for the variables, as I illustrate in "[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169210/6309)")

Comment: @ЮрийШиповалов Did you set the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY/HTTPS_PROXY`? Did you use an http URL for the proxy?

Comment: C:\Users\YShipovalov\Projects\src\helloworld>go run main.go
..\github.com\gin-gonic\gin\binding\default_validator.go:11:2: cannot find packa
ge "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8" in any of:
        C:\Users\YShipovalov\Projects\src\github.com\gin-gonic\gin\vendor\gopkg.
in\go-playground\validator.v8 (vendor tree) after run main.go. All packages are downloaded in GOPATH

Comment: @ЮрийШиповалов So the go get has worked? (sice you do have a github.com\gin-gonic\gin). Can you try glide or govendor (https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/757#issuecomment-265369437) in order to make sure gin has all its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version is not that important!
The:

`$ go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin`

Should work correctly!! 
Fixed version is for when you want n specific version!